# Unable to boot linux ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, boot, troubleshooting

Getting lvmetad is not active yet , using direct activation during sysinit

/dev/mapper/dhcp--10--47--100--93-vg-root:clean

We are able to boot through bootable USB.

Using Ubuntu 16.04 version .

[image]Any solution to recover other than reinstalling.

Comment: You need to provide some more info like: 1. Was the pc bootable before, 2. Did you do anything `sudo` related that might have caused this issue.

Comment: @saga what all info like?

Comment: Fill a [bugreport](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs)

Comment: @saga yes sudo might have caused the problem